# Getting view from any application to move arrow cursor

Tags: android

I am creating a test-application in android and playing with the keyboard.

I want to create a custom keybaord layout with my own arrow keys(like in some commercial products).

What I am unable to find is :

1. how do we get the view which has focus in any application? The keyboard is running as service, and i need this to be usable in all applications. I cannot call findById as this might be some third party application.
2. When I click the arrow keys, the cursor should move(up, down, left, right) in the view the cursor is currently in.

Any idea how to start this?

Comment: i think if i can access the third-part app's edit-text or whatever, then i might be able to move the cursor, so the main question is how to get the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following function:

```
sendDownUpKeyEvents(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT);
sendDownUpKeyEvents(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT);
sendDownUpKeyEvents(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP);
sendDownUpKeyEvents(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN);
```

respectively

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great open source keyboard project hosted on github. Dive into the source code and you'll find everything you are looking for and many things you probably hadn't thought of too :-)

https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard

Comment: do you know if it has ways to move cursor pointer(i know how to do move, but selection on right is a problem for me).

Comment: Im not sure but it might. You'll have to go through the source code and find out.

Comment: I found the source of another keyboard called hacker's keybord which helped. While this was not the answer i'll vote it up for help :)